# How to fix duplicate column names preventing plot_cells(cds) from running?

Tags: r, ggplot2

1. Problem Summary

I'm using the monocle3 package for RNA-seq analyses.
After creating a cds using `new_cell_data_set()` to combine three .csv files (see code below), I am trying to use the `plot_cells()` function, but this error message keeps appearing:

```
Error: Column name `sample_name` must not be duplicated.
```

I run rlang::last_trace(), and this is the output:

```
> rlang::last_trace()
x
+-<error/tibble_error_column_names_must_be_unique>
| Column name `sample_name` must not be duplicated.
\-<error/vctrs_error_names_must_be_unique>
  Names must be unique.
Backtrace:
     x
  1. \-monocle3::plot_cells(cds)
  2.   \-`%>%`(...)
  3.     +-base::withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
  4.     \-base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  5.       \-base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  6.         \-monocle3:::`_fseq`(`_lhs`)
  7.           \-magrittr::freduce(value, `_function_list`)
  8.             \-function_list[[i]](value)
  9.               +-dplyr::group_by(., cell_group)
 10.               \-dplyr:::group_by.data.frame(., cell_group)
 11.                 \-dplyr::grouped_df(groups$data, groups$group_names, .drop)
 12.                   \-dplyr:::compute_groups(data, vars, drop = drop)
 13.                     +-tibble::as_tibble(data)
 14.                     \-tibble:::as_tibble.data.frame(data)
 15.                       \-tibble:::lst_to_tibble(unclass(x), .rows, .name_repair)
 16.                         \-tibble:::set_repaired_names(x, .name_repair)
 17.                           +-rlang::set_names(...)
 18.                           \-tibble:::repaired_names(...)
 19.                             +-tibble:::subclass_name_repair_errors(...)
 20.                             | \-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 21.                             \-vctrs::vec_as_names(...)
 22.                               \-(function () ...
 23.                                 \-vctrs:::validate_unique(names = names, arg = arg)
 24.                                   \-vctrs:::stop_names_must_be_unique(names, arg)
 25.                                     \-vctrs:::stop_names(...)
 26.                                       \-vctrs:::stop_vctrs(class = c(class, "vctrs_error_names"), ...)
```

2. What I've tried

Based on what I found while researching the problem on Google/stackoverflow, I tried to check for duplicated names in the cds (please let me know if there are better ways to check for duplicated column names) using the code below (output is included).

```
duplicated(cds)
LogicalList of length 55
[[1]] logical(0)
[[2]] logical(0)
[[3]] logical(0)
[[4]] logical(0)
[[5]] logical(0)
[[6]] logical(0)
[[7]] logical(0)
[[8]] logical(0)
[[9]] logical(0)
[[10]] logical(0)
...
<45 more elements>
```

```
anyDuplicated(cds)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[10] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[19] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[28] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[46] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[55] FALSE
```

```
anyDuplicated(cds, fromLast = TRUE)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[10] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[19] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[28] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[46] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[55] FALSE
```

I also checked `pData(cds)`, and there is only one column name called "sample_name" out of the 59 columns.

The below code appeared to run, but the same error message appeared when I ran `plot_cells(cds)`, and when I re-checked the `pData(cds)`, the column's name was still "sample_name", so I'm not sure if it made a change.

```
names(cds)[names(cds) == "sample_name"] <- "sample"
```

Additionally, I tried a more specific version of `plot_cells()`, and below is the similar, but different error message in the output:

```
plot_cells(cds,color='cell_type_designation_label',show_trajectory_graph=FALSE,label_cell_groups=FALSE)
            Error: `data` must be uniquely named but has duplicate columns
rlang::last_trace()
        <error/rlang_error>
        `data` must be uniquely named but has duplicate columns
        Backtrace:
             x
          1. +-(function (x, ...) ...
          2. \-ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
          3.   +-ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
          4.   \-ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
          5.     \-ggplot2:::by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
          6.       \-ggplot2:::f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
          7.         \-l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
          8.           \-ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
          9.             \-ggplot2:::scales_add_defaults(...)
         10.               \-base::lapply(aesthetics[new_aesthetics], eval_tidy, data = data)
         11.                 \-rlang:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
```

`colnames(cds)` shows each column being named after a gene, and since there are over 1000 genes, I don't know the easiest way to check for duplicates (which there shouldn't be).

`pData(cds)$sample_name` shows each cell's specific tag, and there are over 1000 of these as well, making it hard to check for duplicates.

For reference,

```
> dim(cds)
[1]    55 14771
```

Therefore, I think there's definitely issues with duplicated columns/column names, but I don't know where to look in the cds to identify where the columns are duplicated, as well as how to fix it. Thank you in advance!

3. Additional code used

Below is the code used to combine the three .csv files to create the new_cell_data_set. Some aligning with columns/rows has to occur for the labels to match the features.

```
cds <- new_cell_data_set(expression_data = expression_matrix_2,
                                 cell_metadata = cell_metadata,
                                 gene_metadata = gene_annotation)
```

Comment: You could check whether `validObject(cds)` returns TRUE, and do some tests like `length(unique(pData(cds)$sample_name)) == length(pData(cds)$sample_name)`. `colnames(cds) <- make.names(colnames(cds), unique = TRUE)` or `make.unique(colnames(cds))` and similar  - this would append .1, .2,.. etc. to the duplicated names, if there are any.

Comment: @user12728748
Thank you for the suggestion! Here's the output with the code below:

`validObject(cds)
[1] TRUE`

`> length(unique(pData(cds)$sample_name)) == length(pData(cds)$sample_name)
[1] TRUE`

I tried both ways to make `colnames(cds)` unique, and while the code lines ran, the same error occurred when running `plot_cells(cds)`. Do you have any idea why the changes aren't being applied? Thanks!

Comment: Based on your tests, colnames(cds) are unique, but, based on the error, there seems to be an issue with the colname `sample_name` itself. I am not familiar with the workflow, but does the example fom the vignette work for you? Do you maybe need to run additional steps before running, `plot_cells`, such as `preprocess_cds` and `reduce_dimension`? If examples do not work, perhaps reinstalling the package or installing the latest version from github might help.

Comment: @user12728748 I have ran `preprocess_cds` and `reduce_dimension`, as well as `cluster_cells`, before `plot_cells(cds)`, which usually works. Sorry, which vignette are you referring to?

After trying some other ideas, I have also discovered that:
`> which(duplicated(pData(cds)$sample_name))
integer(0)`

`> length(duplicated(pData(cds)$sample_name))
[1] 14771`

I don't see how ALL of the values could be duplicated, since there are 14771 total values. When I run `colnames(cds)`, each column name is a DIFFERENT gene, so I'm not sure if the issue came from combining three .csv files.

Comment: @user12728748

Troubleshooting that hasn't made a difference and resulted in the same error message when `plot_cells(cds)` is run after:

`cds <- cds[, !duplicated(pData(cds)$sample_name)]`

`valid_column_names <- make.names(names=names(cds), unique=TRUE, allow_ = TRUE)
names(cds) <- valid_column_names`

`valid_column_names <- make.names(names=names(pData(cds)), unique=TRUE, allow_ = TRUE)
names(pData(cds)) <- valid_column_names`

`cds_2 <- cds[, !duplicated(pData(cds)$sample_name) ]`

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the type of some of the metadata columns not playing nicely with Monocle.

Print

```
pData(cds)
```

and check the type of the metadata columns. I had this error when two columns had been imported as a matrix rather than a vector (factor, character or numeric are all OK).

Simply doing

```
pData(cds)$column_name <- factor(pData(cds)$column_name)
```

Should solve the issue.

Or, if you don't care about the metadata, just remove it.

```
pData(cds) <- NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

in case someone needs as a reference. I saw the same error when I was trying to convert a Seurat object of scRNA-seq into a monocle3 object. I don't have duplications in my cell barcodes, and I wondered if it could be that there is a column named "sample_name" in my scRNA-seq metadata, which might contradict the intrinsic data slot/column of the same name within the monocle cds object. I named it something else and the problem was cleared.

Answer (score -3):

May you data has one col names 'sample_name' , just remove it